# Get the text from textfield when click on backspace button Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I need to get the text from `textfield` when I click over the backspace.

**For Example :**

I have a phone `textfield`. When I click on each key, there is a search happens and it works fine using "`shouldChangeCharactersInRange`" delegate. Once I delete any character from any where in the `textfield` I need to get the rest of `textfield` text and need to search. How can I achieve this?

Comment: shouldChangeCharactersInRange calls when u delete the text in text field

Comment: i know that, I need the rest of text from textfield

Comment: It is as @ismail sais. I do not get the problem too.

Comment: Which "rest" are you talking about. The text field has a getter method for the text. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register for the below notification, then you will get notified for any text change.
Then in the textFieldDidChange: method you can examine the contents of the textField

```
[textField addTarget:self 
                  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    // Handle change.
    UITextField* txt = (UITextField*)sender;
    NSLog(@"txt = %@",txt.text);

   //Write code to search from array or anything else.

}
```

Comment: @ekta Makadiya r u sure on this typecasting is needed?

Answer (score 0):

To get search text from `UITextField` using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method you can use:

```
 NSString *searchText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```